# sensor not working in android game application

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am developing an android game application.I have implemented the shake listener and the sensor.The Code is not containing any error.But when i deploy the application on android device Sensor is not working.Can anybody tell how should i pursue.Where is my error. I have reffered the url for shaking listener and sensor http://www.clingmarks.com/?p=25

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure your android manifest is correct? make sure your application requests the usage of the accelerometer.

Also that code is very old I think some of the API's have changed, there is an accelerometer example in the example projects on eclipse if you want a better/current example.

Comment: Narhem how can i check whether my android manifest file is correct?

Comment: I am not able to find the example you are mentioning.Could u plz paste the code here? Thanks

Comment: sorry I was asleep then I had to go to school,
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/index.html is the link for the accelerometer example, but if your SDK is up to date just right click new android project, from an example, then choose accelerometer play.

Comment: There is no permission for accelerometer. It just works.